# How to count used cells in a row if some cells are blank

Tags: vba, excel

How to count used cell in row if some cells are blank

```
Sub atest()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Dim LC As Long, s As Long
Dim myrange As String
LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LC = Range((LR) & Column.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Comment: Why not just use COUNTA

Answer (score 2):

Just use the native COUNTA() function, you can access this via the `WorksheetFunction` Class

```
cellCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(LR.EntireRow)
```

No point re-inventing the wheel when there is already a perfectly good function to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than starting at the end of the data to get your max number of columns, it's easier to do this on headers using `Cells()`

```
Sub atest()

Dim LR As Long, _
    i As Long, _
    LC As Long, _
    s As Long, _
    MyRange As String

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        LR = .Rows(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'Or
        'LR = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        LC = .Range(.Cells(1, Columns.Count)).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'Or
        'LC = .Range(.Cells(LR,Columns.Count)).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks R3uK but getting error object req in                                                                                                                      "LC = ."(Cells(1,Column.Count)).End (xltoleft).column

Comment: Actually I am match row cell by cell based on equal value  my data range start from column "B" and in last raw there some blank data

Comment: My bad, I forgot an "s", because `.Count` is a collection property so it is `Columns.Count`. Test the edit!

Answer (score 0):

> How to count used cell in row if some cells are blank

This should count only used cells

```
Sub CountUsedCells()
    Dim CountUsedCells   As Long
        CountUsedCells = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).count
    MsgBox " Total used cells are " & CountUsedCells
End Sub
```

Comment: `xlCellTypeConstants` doesn't include cells containing formulas.

Comment: I want match the tow rows data cell by cell  if there some blank cell as well . first row is last row  and second row is lastrow+(-1 row), if value not match then change the background colur of sceound last row cell.